# Shopify Dawn Theme - Pop Up Text when Mouse Hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, tooltip

I am creating my website and using the Dawn theme, from Shopify.

I want to create this effect where I have these numbered circles with a small text and when I mouse hover the circles a more descriptive text shows up next to it. Check the screenshot below. I found it in another website and it's basically and I want to replicate:

[image: Screenshot]

I've read about tooltip and tried creating a page with the tooltip text that will then be placed in the frontpage of my website.

I have already managed to make it work, but I am struggling with 3 things:

1. The hover text is all in a straight column and I want it to have the same appearance as the screenshot above.
2. I want that the hover text from the 2 buttons shows up in the same position. If I create a 3rd button or more I want the text to pop up always in the same position for the multiple buttons.
3. I need to add these numbered circles and when I move the mouse over it, the circle would be filled in black. Tried searching but didn't find any explanation online.

```html
<body>

<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color:
  color:;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  left: 200%;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>


<div class="tooltip">NO EFFORT
  <span class="tooltiptext"><h2>NO EFFORT</h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>Leave it in for just a few hours or overnight, to curl your hair while you sleep!</span>
</div>




<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>



<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color:
  color:;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  left: 200%;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>


<div class="tooltip">NO HEAT = NO DAMAGE
  <span class="tooltiptext"><h2>NO HEAT = NO DAMAGE</h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>Get the healthiest, biggest, bounciest curls you've ever had without any of the extreme damage caused by heated hair tools.</span>
</div>





</body>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? And could you include the relevant code you have so far?

Comment: @AHaworth I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Please put code into your question, not images of it. And to make it easier for us to debug please create a runnable snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I've now edited my question. I'm getting closer, but still struggling with some things that I couldn't find an explanation anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is indeed "tooltips" what you are looking for.
Please see this page for examples: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/html/html-button-tooltip/

Comment: I've seen the examples on that link but the result is not as I pretend. Please check my revised question.

Comment: Dear Tiago, the code in the link is only an example and you will have to research how to implement this in a way that it looks to your preference. Please search for CSS fundamentals and I am sure you will find plenty of material on how to change certain aspects of your web design.

Comment: I tried following the examples on the link provided (about the design I will care about it later) but I'm struggling to link the HTML code with the CSS file created.

Comment: You can try one of the methods described here: https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_howto.asp

Comment: I think I managed to do it without linking the HTML to the CSS. I've edited my question, because now I have a different problem, but getting closer to the desired result.